# epson scanner v600 not working

Tags: drivers, software-installation

Cannot get my v600 usb scanner to work. Looking for epson drivers, I found [this site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult). I downloaded drivers there :

- iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
- iscan-data_1.23.0-1_all.deb

and installed them. But my scanner is still not recognized. I use ubuntu 13.04. simple scan, iscan or xsane scan  can not see the device.

Answer (score 2):

I just got my Epson v600 scanner working on Ubuntu 18.04 by doing the following.

1. Download and install the drivers from
   http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule
2. create these linked files

`sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

3. Create a file called /etc/udev/rules.d/79-udev-epson.rules with this content:

ATTRS{manufacturer}=="EPSON", DRIVERS=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0777"

4. Power cycle the scanner.

If I didn't do step 3, I had to use sudo to run iscan.  After including step 3 I could use the icon to launch iscan or launch it from the command line without sudo.  I also tested the scanner with the XSane Image program and that works too.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Currently using Mint 19.2.

Comment: Still working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

'Just found the solution !

I had used gdebi to install the three packages (iscan core, data and plugin). But, it is necessary to install EACH package one after the other as described here : http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00002.html

Regards,

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.