# Does the Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner or V550 Work with SANE

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner

Before buying either the Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner or the Epson Perfection V550, I would like to confirm from a person who has used either of these scanners under Linux that they work with [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html). The SANE documentation may be out of date.

The Perfection V550 and V600 are listed as "**not supported**".  The model 500 appears to now be obsolete as the current model is now the 550 and it is not listed in SANE.

I would like to know, from a person who has used these scanners, if these scanners work with SANE.

As an alternative, [Epson does have a website for downloading Linux drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [epson scanner v600 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351629/epson-scanner-v600-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for people looking for the answer: it seems Epson updated the package and now provides a "single install" package. (http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=perfection-v550&version=1.0.0) This is a `.tar.gz` with the `.deb` files mentioned by Gerhard Kulzer and an `install.sh` script to install the packages in the right order:

```
tar xaf iscan-perfection-v550-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-perfection-v550-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb
sudo sh install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Version Ver. 1.0.1(07-2016). Location, as of the date of this post, is:  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=47262&DSCCHK=d177e2e8a56fec619d2b1b033dd50bae38ffc60f

Answer (score 0):

Yes they work together, you have to install

```
iscan-data_1.33.0-1_all.deb 
iscan_2.30.0-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
iscan-plugin-gt-x820_2.2.0-1_amd64.deb
```

in that order, download from Epson

Comment: Can you please explain how to install these? (The order doesn't matter by the way. The package configuration process will take care of that.)

Answer (score 0):

No, iscan is out of date, it requires old libraries that are not in modern versions of Linux.

Comment: any other driver to get these things working?

Answer (score 0):

help available here! bug in 18.04 && 18.10

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012

tldr;

`sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

worked for me, given that i already installed the iscan perfection bundle and had my scanner showing up in `sane-find-scanner`. the library shuffle fixed my failed `scanimage -L`